# Replace null values in 1 column with data from another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to replace all null data in column `count_1` with data that may be in column `count_2`. Below is the expected output with a given input. How can I do this in Spark Scala?

Input Dataframe

```
name   count_1 count_2
Java   10000   null
Python null    20000
Scala  30000   null
R      null    null
Swift  50000   65000
```

Output Dataframe

```
name   merged
Java   10000
Python 20000
Scala  30000
R      null
Swift  50000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a coalesce on the said columns

This is what I would do (this would work if you have more columns like count_4):

```
// find columns to do a coalesce
val cols = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("count")).map(col(_)

// do the actual coalesce
df.select($"name", coalesce(cols: _*).as("merged"))
```